# .htaccess Subdomain in a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I'm building an application, and I'd like to map subdomain 'x' to `example.com/_sub/x/` but only if folder 'x' exists in folder '_sub'. If it does not, I'd like example.com to be displayed. The following works, but only if the files or folders also exist inside of folder x.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/_sub/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's another way of looking at it.

```
doesNotExist.example.com -> example.com
test.example.com         -> test.example.com
example.com              -> example.com
```

Here's my updated code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#If the file and directory exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/_sub/%1/$1 [P]

#If the directory exists but the file does not
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/_sub/%1/404.html [P]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this may solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899206/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-cache-using-htaccess-load-normal-script-if-no

Comment: Unfortunately that's for directories on the same domain/subdomain, and I'm not sure how to adjust it to work for me.

Comment: ok maybe this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770435/mod-rewrite-if-file-exists see Mathieu Parents solution

Comment: I've almost got it to work, but it redirects links without an ending filename such as 'test.example.com/test/' now goes to 'test.example.com/404.html'. Basically if gives a false negative for line `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -f`

Comment: I've added my updated code if anyone has an suggestions.

Comment: Is back reference %1 indeed capturing the sub-domain name? If it isn't, there's the reason for the problem in your last comment. Try temporarily with [P,R] flags to **see** the redirected URL.

Comment: Yes it was capturing it, I ended up building a quick php file to check that, [P,R] would have been a lot easier though :) Turns out I needed to add an or statement: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -d`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was initially having was solved by adding a second set of rules to send none existent files to the local 404 page. Once I figured this out, I then found out that everything worked except links without trailing files. I simply added the `[OR]` statement and following line to fix this. Hopefully this is of some help to others in my position.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the file and directory exists
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/_sub/%1/$1 [P]

# If the directory exists but the file does not
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/ -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_sub/%1/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/_sub/%1/404.html [P]
</IfModule>
```